# VBA UserForm Listview control - mouse click coordinates and positioning

Tags: vba, listview, position, userform

VBA userforms, and listviews in particular, are tricky when it comes to spatial distances and coordinates. The question I am trying to solve is: the mousedown event gives the coordinates in pixles - how do I transform that into the units required for repositioning another user control and also incorporate the width property of user controls.

To give the very specific problem:
I have a listview with multiple columns and a horizontal scroll bar. I want to get the selected row and column of the mouse click and then reposition a frame to the point at which the mouse was clicked.

Googling only came up with partial answers - nothing solving the full problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three different units of measurement. Pixels, twips and imperial points.

- Converting between twips and imperial points is easy - 1 imperial
  point is 20 twips.
- Converting between pixels and twips is harder -
  though many solutions are easily googleable. It is dependant on the
  pixel density of your screen.

Once you have gotten your functions/subs down to convert between pixels, twips and imperial points, you can then use the correct coordinate units for each different task:

- `MouseDown` event gives the coordinates in pixels.
- `HitTest` (the listview function to return the selected row -
  although not the selected column) takes coordinates in twips.
- Column widths and all other user control widths are in imperial
  point.
- `GetScrollPos` (the Windows API function to return the scrollbar
  position) gives a value in pixels.
- Repositioning user controls on the userform takes imperial points.